# Escape hash sign in Yaml multiline text

Tags: yaml

Is it possible to escape a hash sign (#) from a multiline text?

```
...
-
    my_story: |
        Line 1
        Line 2
        # Hash line
```

What I was hoping to get is:

```
array {
    'my_story' => 'Line 1
Line 2
# Hash line'
}
```

If I wrap the hash line with quotes I get them in the text:

```
'Line 1
Line 2
"# Hash line"'
```

Any ideas..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape hash (#) character in a multi-line string in yaml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739639/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-a-multi-line-string-in-yaml), which has an accepted (and identical) answer

Answer (score 6):

What you wrote is perfectly fine and '#' should be correctly processed. The following code works just fine in Python 3 (pyyaml)

```
data="""
-
    my_story: |
        Line 1
        Line 2
        # Hash line
"""

import yaml

deserializedData = yaml.load ( data )

print ( deserializedData[0]['my_story'] )
```

The above line prints

```
Line 1
Line 2
# Hash line
```

Comment: I had the same question, but it turned out it was just my IDE formatting lines with hashes as comments. When I ran it, it was correctly processed, as you say.